# Find same value appeared in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
column1   column2   column3
  1          2        4
  2          3        5
  3          4        6
  4          5        7
  5          6        8
```

How would I able to find the values appear among these three columns?

Like in the above dataframe the output will be [4,5]

I tried the code

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   for i in row["column1"]:
       for j in row["column2"]:
           if row["column1"][i] == row["column2"][j]:
              print row["column1"][i]
```

and it jumps out the error

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

I also tried

```
for i in df["column1"].iterrows():
```

and the error is

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.** You also haven't clearly explained what the operation you're trying to perform is. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Sorry for ambiguous. So for the example Dataframe I provided, I wish the output will be [4,5] (4 and 5)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
s=df.melt().groupby('value').variable.nunique().loc[lambda x : x==df.shape[1]]
value
4    3
5    3
Name: variable, dtype: int64

#s.index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy intersect1d,

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(np.intersect1d, list(df.to_numpy().T))

Output: array([4, 5])
```

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly what I'm looking for!